# core.async channel as an atom

Tags: clojure, core.async

I am building an application that consumes a file, and produces another file. It's not terribly important what it does, but I want to use core.async; main reason is I want to learn it, but also to be able to make this processing potentially faster on multicore machines.

I want the app to have 2 modes of operation: you can run it from command line, and pass a file on the STDIN, or you can fire up a REPL session, and create your inputs there. I've already used this approach in my Emacs REPL, and I want to be able to use in command-line REPL session.

When run with a file on STDIN, my code creates a channel, creates consumers, and puts the lines unto the channel. When I go interactive, I figured I'll create a channel and bind it to an atom; then there will be an API exposed to add individual messages to the channel, or entire sequences, doesn't matter.

What made me doubt the decision is the absence of examples/articles talking about channel+atom combinations. As if it's not a good pattern.
Would anyone be able to provide their opinions? Perhaps I'm just overthinking this =)
Sorry about the wall-of-text!

Comment: Guess you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any benefit to putting a mutable object in an atom. The purpose of atoms are to act as a mutable container for immutable objects.

I'm guessing you want to hold off initializing the channel, and are `reset!`ing the atom when it's decided that the channel is needed. While this works, I would consider it an abuse of atoms.

I recommend just using a `delay`:

```
(def ch (delay (chan)))

; The chan is initialized here the first time it's dereferenced
@ch

; And the same cached chan is used here
@ch
```

This frees you up from needing to initialize the atom with `nil`, then constantly check if the atom has had a channel added to it before using it.

Comment: That's exactly what I was doing; thanks, I didn't know about the 'delay', guess my break from Clojure was too long.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to simply eval `(def c (chan))` at the REPL. Then you can pass/inspect `c` as needed, but not alter the structure of your program.

It's not uncommon to find a comment form at the end of a .clj file with helpers intended to be evaluated at the REPL. For example:

```
(comment
  (def c (chan))
  (do-something-with-c c))
```

Comment: I like the idea too; I certainly feel more comfortable around Clojure after this reintroduction exercise; but the disadvantage here is, user needs to speak core.async :)